# Как сделать активными элементы контекстного меню?

Tags: c#, winforms

Делаю небольшой аналог блокнота, столкнулся с задачей: нужно сделать активными элементы контекстного меню, когда часть текста, или весь он, выделен курсором мыши в richtextbox. Собственно, чтоб можно было вырезать, скопировать выделенный текст.
Не знаю, как сделать активными menuitem, когда некий текст выделен курсором. Изначально они не активны.
Подскажите, пожалуйста. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При вызове меню, проверяй `richTextBox1.SelectedText.Length>0` и делай активнымм или неактивным пункт меню.

Comment: Спасибо!Блин,стыдно даже,что не додумался.Спасибо ещё раз!)

Comment: Всегда рад помочь!